# Getting overdue email for deleted task

Tags: workflow, email, tasks, server-farm

Going through a weird problem for a deleted task. Scheduler sends email still.

Running two production servers (SVR1 & SRV2). Dev database was restored in production. So in email body, item link is having Dev server's URL. But the emails are not throwing from Dev server. After analyzing the email headers, I found that emails are throwing from SRV2 only. After Googling, I performed following actions:

- Removed all old versions of the workflow
- Removed all items from recycle bin in all servers (Prod & Dev)
- Cleared farm configuration cache from all servers

What else I can do to get rid of this weird email?

Comment: What you mean emails are throwing from Dev servers? is the email containing the Dev Site URL? did you hardcoded the URL in the email body?

Comment: it's a mistake. mails are not throwing from Dev servers

Comment: Look into any farm solutions, powershell scripts on a task scheduler, custom timer jobs, anything of that nature that could be spoofing these emails. Is it the same alert/overdue template? Try to change the overdue message in the workflow and republish and see if that changes the email body--if not it's an orphaned workflow version that maybe you can find in powershell.